# Starting fig process with supervisor

Tags: django, docker, supervisord, fig

I am having issues stopping fig process with supervisor.

```
supervisorctl start web_app
```

successfully starts the webserver, returns a status or RUNNING and a certain pid.

When I run

```
supervisorctl stop web_app
```

the process *seems* to get terminated because state becomes STOPPED and pid goes to 0, but the actual docker containers keep running and the web app never terminates.

supervisor.conf:

```
[program:web_app]
command = fig --file /home/luna/docker_test/fig.yml up
stopasgroup = true
killasgroup = true
autostart = false
autorestart = true
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looked over fig source code and found that I had to add `stopsignal = INT` to supervisor.conf